# Проблемы с конвертированием из .fbd (firebird) в excel

Tags: excel, firebird

Есть большой файл базы данных *Firebird*, там несколько таблиц, их все нужно между собой связать и построить одну таблицу.

У меня уже почти все готово, но проблема вот в чем:

Есть в бд таблица, называется `RT_WORKS`, так вот в этой таблице есть поле `WORK_NAME`. У заказчика в программе, через которую вся эта бд постепенно создавалась(программа называется автодилер). В этом поле осмысленные названия(например "замена тормозных колодок"). У меня та же самая база показывает непонятные наборы из заглавных английских и цифр.

Например: `CF5B2263038547E2798A9FE9D77A36514D492035923C8313AC925C3960DBCA3D70C896538B9C07BA`.

Кто - нибудь может подсказать, что это и как это перевести в читаемый вид?

Comment: Откройте базу через IB Expert и посмотрите, как в нем выглядят эти поля.

Comment: там то же самое. как думаете -- может быть это проблема в кодировке?

Comment: Наверняка в кодировке - при подключении к БД нужно указать правильную.

Comment: использовал все кириллические кодировки, которые знаю..не помогло.
если что, все эти строки состоят из HEX - символов, т.е. 0-9 и A-F